# What is a TimeSpan serialized into in ServiceStack JSON

Tags: servicestack-text

In JSON from ServiceStack, Timespan values look like `P5D` for 5 days, etc. What is the name of this format, where is it defined? I need to parse it in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the XSD Time format. If you're using [ServiceStack's new Swift Add Reference Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swift-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) this should be transparently supported.

Otherwise you should be able to re-use the ServiceStack.Swift [TimeSpan serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Swift/blob/master/src/ServiceStackClient/ServiceStackClient/Json.swift#L215) implementation.